# Is there a quick way to check the significance for each category of a predictor?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, post-hoc

I ran a chi-square test of independence on this data set.

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  category  true false
       <dbl> <int> <int>
1          1   101   633
2          2  1241  4122
3          3  1211  3642
4          4   250   520
5          5    39   188
```

My understanding is that tests the null hypothesis `there is no significant difference between any single category against any other category`.

I'd like to know if each individual category is significantly different from the rest.

I believe I could test that by reformatting the data so it looks like this

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  category  true false
       <dbl> <int> <int>
1          1   101   633
2      Other  2741  8472
```

And then have each category take-turns for the "hot seat" of being placed against the rest.

1) Is that the right way to see if each individual category has a significant difference and 2) is there a function or a fast way to do that in R?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tukey+hsd.